# bash append text at the start and end of ls output

Tags: unix, sed, append, ls

I want to change the output of ls from:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

Into

```
Start [1.png] End
Start [2.png] End
Start [3.png] End
```

I need to append a string at the start and end of a line at the same time.
I'm not opposed to using text files to store the output however I avoid it if there is a better way.

I know I can use

```
ls | sed 's/^/Start [/'
```

and

```
ls | sed 's/$/] End/'
```

However is there a way to combine these 2 operations into 1 statement? And avoid using temporary text files?

Comment: `sed 's/[0-9]*\.png/Start [&] End/'`?

Comment: less elegant than @WiktorStribiżew but closer to your code : `ls | sed 's/^/Start [/' | sed 's/$/] End/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | sed 's/^/Start [/' | sed 's/$/] End/'
```

Found out myself by experimenting.

Comment: you could also use `sed 's/.*/Start [&] End/'` for this case.. see also [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

I found easier using `xargs`, give a try to:

```
$ xargs < <(ls) -I@ echo "start [ @ ] END"
```

`-I@` will help to use `@` as a placeholder so then you could use `echo "start [ @ ] END` and `@` will be replaced with the output from `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
ls | awk '{print "start [" $0 "] END"}'
```

OR

```
ls | sed 's/^/start \[/;s/$/\] end/'
```

Comment: you are missing the brackets

Comment: @gogaz, sure done that now, thanks a lot for letting know.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed  's/^/start [ /;s/$/ ] end/' 
start [ 1.png ] end
start [ 2.png ] end
start [ 3.png ] end
```